# Accessing table names in .mdb file using Python package Adodbapi

Tags: python

I'm writing an application in Python and I'm using the Adodbapi package to handle my sql queries. For one part of the code, I need to communicate with an Access '97 (no, it's not a typo) database, and I want to get a list of the table names via an SQL statement. I've tried a bunch of statements using MSysObjects but I run into permissions isssues - no I don't have the option of opening the db in access and changing the permissions. I would imagine that Adodbapi has a way of accessing Schema information but I can't manage to find it.

Thanks in advance for your help.